# Removing courtesy time signature

Tags: lilypond

I have a time signature change over a barline which causes a courtesy time signature on the end of the previous line that I would like to remove. For clarity, I've attached a screenshot of exactly what I'd like to remove; I still want the time change at the beginning of the following line to be visible. [image: Screenshot of a lilypond output file which has a courtesy time signature change boxed in red.]

Answer (score 3):

Just that one?  I think what you need is:

```
\override Score.TimeSignature.break-visibility = #'#(#f #t #t)
```

Then if you want courtesy time signatures again, use `\revert` to cancel it.